# Adding parameter to method as <img src.="[method]"

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, visual-studio-code

I have an image that appears by calling a method, thusly:

```
<img id="myimage" src="/mycontroller/GetImage" title="my image" />
```

This calls my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetImage(bool force = true)
{
   if (force)
   {
      ...
      return val;
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

This works great when the default value for 'force' is true.

What I want to do is add the parameter and set force = false:

```
<img id="myimage" src="/mycontroller/GetImage(true)" title="my image" />
```

and

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetImage(bool force = false)
```

Which fails - force always is false!

I've tried:

```
<img id="myimage" src="/mycontroller/GetImage/true" title="my image" />
```

and in frustration:

```
<img id="myimage" src="/mycontroller/GetImage?force=true" title="my image" />
```

None of which work.

I've also tried a little script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("myimage")[0].src = "/mycontroller/GetImage(true)";
});
</script>
```

No joy.

I'm sure this is a simple issue - lil' help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That parameter gets mapped from the querystring. Have you tried `<img id="myimage" src="/mycontroller/GetImage?force=true" title="my image" />`

Comment: Thanks John! Yes, I have. Doesn't work either.